# CakePHP 2: Using stored array as keys in a $this->Model->find statement

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I have a dropdown on my site that allows for multiple selections:

```
$this->Form->input('systems', array('label'=>'System Assignments', 'empty'=>'', 'default'=>'', 'div'=>false, 'multiple'=>true, 'class'=>'chosen',
                            'options'=>$systems));
```

This code from my controller populates the `$systems` variable:

```
$systems = $this->Discrepancy->find('list', array('fields' => array('id', 'description'),
    'conditions'=>array('Discrepancy.deleted_record' => 0),
    'order'=>array('Discrepancy.display_order'=>'ASC')));
$this->set(compact('systems'));
```

When the user makes their selection(s), the row ID's are stored as an array in a table called `Users` in a field called `systems`.

```
$system_string = implode(',', $this->request->data['User']['systems']);
 $this->request->data['User']['systems'] = $system_string;

systems
-------
 50,22
```

On my Edit screen, I would like to be able to use that array of values as my list of ID's for retrieving and displaying the user's system choices, by adding a 'value' parameter to the dropdown.

```
'value'=>array_key($chosen_systems);
```

How can I use these stored values in a $this->Model->find statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Guess I needed to write it all out first.

Put the following line in the $this->Model->find statement:

```
'conditions'=>array('Discrepancy.id'=>explode(',',$var_for_systems_from_db))
```